# How to Gather Data with The Same ID from Other Row using R

Tags: r

I'm using R Studio for data analyzing. I met a dataset that include the same ID but it have different row just like the below example

| ID | Age | Status_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 21 | 2006 |
| 1 | 22 | 2007 |

May I know how to change it or edit it as below or something better than below?

| ID | Age | Status_Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 | 2007 |

Comment: What is it exactly that you want? To keep the last row of the same ID? If so, using `dplyr` you could use `data.frame %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(n())`

Comment: The same ID has different data in different row. I want that ID change to 1 row, then the **Age** and **Status_Year** will be the latest data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could do

```
data.frame %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  arrange(Status_Year) %>%
  slice(n())
```

Note: I added `arrange(Status_Year)` just to make sure the last row of each "ID" is the  latest data.

Comment: Hi there, may I know what is the meaning of **n()** in the **slice**?

Comment: It is to extract the last row of each group.